# How to convert conditional for-loop into list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a `for` loop with `if` condition which I am wanting to convert to list comprehension the loop looks like this

```
if options.accounts.lower() == "all":
    orgPaginator = org.get_paginator('list_accounts_for_parent')
    for orgPages in orgPaginator.paginate(ParentId=src_ou_id):
        for account in orgPages['Accounts']:
            acc.append(account["Id"])
else:
    for account in options.accounts.split(','):
        acc.append(account)
```

This is what I have right now I could figure out the else part but I am having issues converting the first part of it

```
[<??> if options.accounts.lower() == "all" else acc.append(account) for account in options.accounts.split(',')]
```

Can someone provide some guidance on how to convert the first part of this with an explanation?

Comment: I would really not attempt to write this as a list comprehension. It is likely to be almost unreadable, not least because one branch of the `if` has two nested loops and the other only one.

Comment: This is not list comprehension material

Comment: @Nick: It's fine as *two* list comprehensions, where you choose which one to go with based on the existing outer `if`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I wasn't trying to say it couldn't be done, just that a list comprehension would probably be incomprehensible :)

Comment: Why do you want to do convert this into list comprehension?

Answer (score 0):

```
if options.accounts.lower() == "all":
    acc += [account["Id"] for account in [orgPages["Accounts"] for orgPages in org.get_paginator('list_accounts_for_parent').paginate(ParentId=src_ou_id)]]
else:
    acc += [account for account in options.accounts.split(',')]
```

This should do it. I don't think a pure list comprehension method would be better if even possible.

Your `<??>` seems to be what you actually want to put in the list:

```
[f(x) for x in iterable]
```

In this case f(x) would be x[...].

Comment: Thanks for taking look at it I did try `acc += [account["Id"] for account in [orgPages["Accounts"] for orgPages in org.get_paginator('list_accounts_for_parent')]]` but this is throwing this error ```ERROR! Uncaught Exception in run: 'Organizations.Paginator.ListAccountsForParent' object is not iterable```

Comment: my bad, I forgot to copy some of your code... Should work now

Comment: Its throwing a diff error now ```ERROR! Uncaught Exception in run: list indices must be integers or slices, not str```

Comment: I think its the account["Id"] which is causing the issue

Comment: well I just copied that from your code... did your code work before?

Comment: yes it was working,  when I remove the "Id" from account["Id"], it seems to be working fine but it then gets everything whereas I was only wanting "Id"

Comment: what kind of object is account? you could also try to omit the ["id"] initially and then do `acc += map(lambda x: x["Id"], [...])` I don't see why it would be different but I also don't see how the account["Id"] can work in your code and not mine...

Comment: `acc += [account for account in options.accounts.split(',')]` should really just be `acc += options.accounts.split(',')`; `str.split` already returns a `list`, and even if it returned some other iterable, it wouldn't matter, because `list`'s `+=` handles arbitrary iterables.

Answer (score 0):

I/We can get it to this (edit: with help from @ShadowRanger):

```
acc += [p['Accounts'] for p in org.get_paginator('list_accounts_for_parent').paginate(ParentId=src_ou_id)] \
        if options.accounts.lower() == "all" else \
        options.accounts.split(',')
```

Comment: `[a for a in options.accounts.split(',')]` can just be `options.accounts.split(',')`, no listcomp needed. And `[a for a in (p['Accounts'] for p in org.get_paginator('list_accounts_for_parent').paginate(ParentId=src_ou_id))]` should really be `[p['Accounts'] for p in org.get_paginator('list_accounts_for_parent').paginate(ParentId=src_ou_id)]` (why use a no-op listcomp around a genexpr when it could be a single listcomp doing the work?).

Comment: @ShadowRanger yes of course - silly me - thanks.